# How to run sudo command/ call python in ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I just started programming in Ruby, I would like to know if you can run a command like
"Sudo python XXX.py"

I tried to work with RubyPython, but without success because I do not know how and where is the path of the file to be retrieved.

Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: Is there any reason why running the program as root wouldn't work?

Comment: It's not good to run programs as 'root'. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> try using system method from kernel module
>
> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Comment: thank you very much, a question:
can the called program return a value?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: try this

```
command_output = `sudo python DIRECTORY`
  p command_output
```

Where DIRECTORY is the full path of the script you want to execute.

There are several methods, each with their own differences.

Check out this blog entry: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/how-execute-external-shell-command-expansion

```
# define your variable

dir='/tmp'

# execute your shell command

puts `ls #{dir}`
```

EDIT: Check out this stack overflow question:
[Running a shell command from Ruby: capturing the output while displaying the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682837/running-a-shell-command-from-ruby-capturing-the-output-while-displaying-the-out)

Comment: with that method am i able to return a value ?

Comment: Try using the new link I added

Comment: i don't think is my case i have a python program to read from a DS18B20 the temperature... and i need to launch that program and recive the temp.